# Prevent creating child forms

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium-embedded

I have C# WinForms application with Cef WebBrowser component. Sometimes webview rises some alerts from js or show errors from adobe flash component.

How can I prevent my form from creating child dialog windows? Or add some listener for that event to close created child form programmatically?

Comment: Is this a custom webbrowser component, or the default from the toolbox?

Comment: It's not default component. It is chromium embedded framework [link](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded)